# Dependency Property Value Precedence and animations

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I am animating some property using `DoubleAnimation`. Before animation is triggered any local or `Setter` changes are properly reflected in the property. After animation completes nothing seems to be able to change the value of the property. I have even tried `ClearValue` and `InvalidateProperty` as well set calling `SetValue` but the value leftover from animation persists. If animation is repeated, the property continues to be animated as expected so it only appears to be locked for non-animation changes.

Is there a way to rectify this behavior? I want to use the animation to change the property value but still be able to change it manually or via a `Setter` to anything else. I know a thing or two about [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) but the behavior I am currently experiencing is a bit strange. I'd hate to have to use "manual animations".

EDIT: Added sample XAML + code.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300"
        x:Name="_this"
        Background="Red">
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
            <Button Click="ToggleOnClick">Toggle!</Button>
            <Button Click="SetHalfOnClick">Set to 0.5!</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding ElementName=_viewbox,Path=Opacity}" />
        <Viewbox x:Name="_viewbox">
            <Viewbox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsToggled,ElementName=_this,Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation To="0.2"
                                                 Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation To="1"
                                                 Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Viewbox.Style>

            <TextBlock Text="Sample!" />
        </Viewbox>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Here is the code:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication7
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1
    {
        public bool IsToggled
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsToggledProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsToggledProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsToggledProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsToggled", typeof(bool), typeof(Window1), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ToggleOnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            IsToggled = !IsToggled;
        }

        private void SetHalfOnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _viewbox.Opacity = 0.5;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit 2 in response to comments:**

In your example you can work around the problem by:

1. Setting `FillBehaviour` to `Stop` on the animation
2. Adding a handler in code to the Completed event:

`<Storyboard Completed="FadeOut_Completed">`

Finally, set the desired 'final' value in the Completed handler (either explicitly or by using the current value of the property

```
private void FadeOut_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   _viewbox.Opacity = _viewbox.Opacity; //this sets the DP value to the animated value
}
```

This works in your sample; hopefully it will work in your problem!

---

**Original Answer**

If you set the [`FillBehaviour`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior.aspx) property of the `Storyboard` to `Stop` (instead of the default value of `HoldEnd`) it will revert to the pre-animation value of the property once the animation completes.  `HoldEnd` causes the animation to maintain its final value on the property

**Update in response to comments:**

As noted in the comments, the animation value will override the value set against the property when `HoldEnd` is specified as the `FillBehaviour`.

This makes it slightly tricky to set the value to something else.

I am not sure if there is a better way to achieve this, but the example below shows one way to work around it.  Its hard to judge how applicable this is without a sample usage from the OP, but in this example I am animating the width of a `Rectangle` on load, and then resetting it to another value when a button is clicked:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Target" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                     From="10" To="100" Duration="0:00:01" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Height="10" Width="10" Fill="Red"  x:Name="Target"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Resize">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Target" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="50" KeyTime="0:00:00" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This works because the *new* animation overrides the value set in the original.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I do want the value to remain after animation completes. I do not want to revert to the old value. The problem I am experiencing is that when animation completes I can no longer change the property no matter what I do.

Comment: That is because the animation is overriding the property value - from the MSDN documentation: "When an animation is applied and is running, the animated value operates at a higher precedence than any value (such as a local value) that the property otherwise has".  If you could post an example of your animation markup and how you are trying to set it after the animation completes it may help

Comment: Just a quick comment. The animation is not running. I can't seem to modify the value after animation *has completed*. I want the last animated value to persist but I also want to be able to change it. I will try to assemble a sample. I deliberately omitted it because the original problem is on Microsoft Surface. I will try to make something simple instead.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the animation has completed, but by setting a `FillBehaviour` of `HoldEnd` it is still treated as active

Comment: I have just created a sample but you seem to have struck gold. If what you say is true then my property is locked forever unless I change animation to `Stop`. But then I don't get the keep-the-animated-value behavior. What is your suggestion?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your superb efforts. I really appreciate that. Unfortunately, your approach is not really applicable in my case. I just want to change the previously animated value at will. I don't have any `Button.Click` events to work with. And even if I did, there is still the problem of retaining the previous value. Your key-frame animation changes that.

Comment: Could you get away with adding another property like `IsToggled` in your example called something like `IsHalfToggled` and then set a new animation on that?

Comment: Probably so in this particular sample. But the sample is an oversimplification. What I need is a reliable way to set `Opacity` to an **arbitrary** value after animation has ended. As it turns out the animation has only ended visually, not technically.

Comment: @wpfwannabe, see my last edit - this works in your example more-or-less as you wanted (I hope!)

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about the same solution but there is another problem in my real world scenario. I am using `By` in my animations. I am animating angles. I don't care what is the angle value at animation start. I just want to animate 180 degrees. So I use `By="180"`. If I set the animation to `Stop` and handle `Completed` how can I tell the last animated value? Let me just say that `180` can be anything else and I do not want to hard-code.

Comment: @wpfwannabe - updated *again* to work when you don't know what the final value is beforehand :)

Comment: Huh, that's all great. It is just that I can't set `Completed` event in a `Style`.

Comment: Why don't you pull the storyboard out into the resource dictionary for your window (or viewbox), set the `Completed` handler on that, and then reference it from within your style as a `StaticResource`?

Comment: Great! It didn't occur to me that this would help! But it did. Hey! That actually finally works! It's a lot of work for a simple task. There is just **ONE** tiny issue. The last animated value in `Completed` is not really the last. It is like one animation frame before last. Do you think there is a way to workaround that?

Comment: Possibly.  I noticed that the `sender` in the event handler is of type `ClockGroup` which allows you access to the animation itself - you may be able to work out the *final* final value from that somehow, but I haven't looked into it

Answer (score 3):

You can use `UIElement.BeginAnimation` with the animation parameter set to *null*. It will clear all animations attached to your property.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but it doesn't work. At least not as simple as that with the sample I posted.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, I have added `            _viewbox.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, null);` in `SetHalfOnClick` before changing `Opacity` and nothing changed.

Comment: In _SetHalfOnClick_ put `_viewbox.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, null);` then `_viewbox.Opacity = 0.5;`. EDIT: Ok... hum...

Comment: From your "hum" I am assuming you have tried it yourself? I wish your approach worked. It would be a simple end to my suffering.

Comment: [ignore this - looked again and realised its wrong] I think I've worked this one out guys - if you use @Nicolas' answer then it does set clear the animated value from `_viewbox`...but your style is applied to all **FrameworkElements**, so the parent container is still only partially opaque

Comment: You can imagine my disappointment. I see the docs say it should do what you say but it doesn't happen. Perhaps because there are really NO animations to clear but instead the property is in some strange internal state which prevents further modification.

Comment: @Steve: I don't think that is right. The style is set explicitly on a `ViewBox` so it shouldn't affect anything else. I opted for `FrameworkElement` because the designer kept throwing this at me: `'Viewbox' TargetType does not match type of element 'PlaceHolderControl'`.